# iOS App error and its causing the app to crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I got this error while running my app for test:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x30d48fd3 0x3b5c1ccf 0x30c82a8b 0x30c8c391 0x1038ab 0x335d45a7 0x335d3efb 0x335ce58b 0x3356a709 0x33569871 0x335cdcc9 0x35bd6aed 0x35bd66d7 0x30d13ab7 0x30d13a53 0x30d12227 0x30c7cf0f 0x30c7ccf3 0x335ccef1 0x335c816d 0x1053c1 0x3baceab7)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Causing the app to crash

Comment: You need to give some more context than that.

Comment: add you code.. it makes to identify where you missed exactly..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more context, it'll be tough to give a good answer. That said, inserting a nil object into an `NSArray`-type class (including `NSMutableArray`) will cause an e exception to be thrown. If you need an "empty" value in an array, use `[NSNull null]`.

To debug this, try enabling an exception breakpoint in Xcode. Here's how:

1. On the lefthand panel, choose the second icon from the right. That's the breakpoints panel.
2. On the bottom corner, there's a little plus. Click it.
3. In the menu, choose "Add Exception Breakpoint"
4. Run your code. When it crashes, it'll show you the line that's crashing, as well as a stack trace.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to insert a nil object. If you want to add nill object you should add as following. You can't add it directly

> [array addObject:[NSNull null]];

Answer (score 0):

You can't add nil to an array (as it holds pointers to the objects) so it crashes. If you need to store nil in an NSArray use NSNull which simply wraps nil into an array.

Comment: Why would you have added it as a comment? It's an answer!

Comment: that nil crashes is already said and that he wants to store NSNull is just a guess, but maybe it is an answer, I'm still new to Stack exchange! :)

Comment: This is definitely an answer so I have removed the bit about the comment.